# Why does n-of show a discontinuity when the size of the reported agentset goes from 2 to 3?

Tags: random, netlogo

The `n-of` reporter is one of those reporters making random choices, so we know that if we use the same `random-seed` we will always get the same agentset out of `n-of`.

`n-of` [takes two arguments](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-of): ***size*** and ***agentset*** (it can also take lists, but a note on this later). I would expect that it works by throwing a pseudo-random number, using this number to choose an agent from ***agentset***, and repeating this process ***size*** times.

If this is true we would expect that, if we test `n-of` on the same ***agentset*** and using the same `random-seed`, but each time increasing ***size*** by 1, every resulting agentset will be the same as in the previous extraction plus a further agent. After all, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers used to pick the first (***size** - 1*) agents was the same as before.

This seems to be confirmed generally. The code below highlights the same patches plus a further one everytime ***size*** is increased, as shown by the pictures:

```
to highlight-patches [n]
  clear-all
  random-seed 123
  
  resize-world -6 6 -6 6

  ask n-of n patches [
    set pcolor yellow
  ]
  
  ask patch 0 0 [
    set plabel word "n = " n
  ]
end
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But there is an exception: the same does not happen when ***size*** goes from 2 to 3. As shown by the pictures below, `n-of` seems to follow the usual behaviour when starting from a ***size*** of 1, but the agentset suddenly changes when ***size*** reaches 3 (becoming the agentset of the figures above - which, as far as I can tell, does not change anymore):

[image]
[image]
[image]

What is going on there behind the scenes of `n-of`, that causes this change at this seemingly-unexplicable threshold?

In particular, this seems to be the case only for `n-of`. In fact, using a combination of `repeat` and `one-of` doesn't show this discontinuity (or at least as far as I've seen):

```
to highlight-patches-with-repeat [n]
  clear-all
  random-seed 123

  resize-world -6 6 -6 6
  
  repeat n [
    ask one-of patches [
      set pcolor yellow
    ]
  ]
  
  ask patch 0 0 [
    set plabel word "n = " n
  ]
end
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note that this comparison is not influenced by the fact that `n-of` guarantees the absence of repetitions while `repeat` + `one-of` may have repetitions (in my example above the first repetition happens when ***size*** reaches 13). The relevant aspect simply is that the reported agentset of ***size*** *x* is consistent with the reported agentset of ***size*** *x + 1*.

---

*On using `n-of` on lists instead of agentsets*

Doing the same on a list results in always different numbers being extracted, i.e. the additional extraction does not equal the previous extraction with the addition of a further number. While this looks to me as a counter-intuitive behaviour from the point of view of expecting always the same items to be extracted from a list if the extraction is based on always the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers, at least it looks to happen consistently and therefore it does not look to me as ambiguous behaviour as in the case of agentsets.

Comment: Elaboration added to my answer!  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's find out how this works together.  Let's start by checking the primitive implementation itself.  [It lives here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-gui/src/main/prim/etc/_nof.java).  Here is the relevant bit with error handling and comments chopped out for brevity:

```java
    if (obj instanceof LogoList) {
      LogoList list = (LogoList) obj;
      if (n == list.size()) {
        return list;
      }
      return list.randomSubset(n, context.job.random);
    } else if (obj instanceof AgentSet) {
      AgentSet agents = (AgentSet) obj;
      int count = agents.count();
      return agents.randomSubset(n, count, context.job.random);
    }
```

So we need to investigate the implementations of `randomSubset()` for lists and agentsets.  I'll start with agentsets.

The [implementation lives here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-core/src/main/agent/AgentSet.scala#L81-L99).  And the relevant bits:

```scala
    val array: Array[Agent] =
      resultSize match {
        case 0 =>
          Array()
        case 1 =>
          Array(randomOne(precomputedCount, rng.nextInt(precomputedCount)))
        case 2 =>
          val (smallRan, bigRan) = {
            val r1 = rng.nextInt(precomputedCount)
            val r2 = rng.nextInt(precomputedCount - 1)
            if (r2 >= r1) (r1, r2 + 1) else (r2, r1)
          }
          randomTwo(precomputedCount, smallRan, bigRan)
        case _ =>
          randomSubsetGeneral(resultSize, precomputedCount, rng)
      }
```

So there you go.  We can see that there is a special case when the `resultSize` is `2`.  It auto-generates 2 random numbers, and flips them to make sure they won't "overflow" the possible choices.  The comment on [the `randomTwo()` implementation](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-core/src/main/agent/ArrayAgentSet.scala#L121-L146) clarifies that this is done as an optimization.  There is similarly a special case for `1`, but that's just `one-of`.

Okay, so now let's check lists.  Looks like [it's implementation of `randomSubset()` lives over here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/parser-core/src/main/core/LogoList.scala#L92-L106).  Here is the snippit:

```scala
  def randomSubset(n: Int, rng: Random): LogoList = {
    val builder = new VectorBuilder[AnyRef]
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    while (j < n && i < size) {
      if (rng.nextInt(size - i) < n - j) {
        builder += this(i)
        j += 1
      }
      i += 1
    }
    LogoList.fromVector(builder.result)
  }
```

The code is a little obtuse, but for each element in the list it's randomly adding it to the resulting subset or not.  If early items aren't added, the odds for later items go up (to 100% if need be).  So changing the overall size of the list changes the numbers that will be generated in the sequence: `rng.nextInt(size - i)`.  That would explain why you don't see the same items selected in order when using the same seed but a larger list.

### Elaboration

Okay, so let's elaborate on the `n = 2` optimization for agentsets.  There are a few things we have to know to explain this:

1. What does the non-optimized code do?

The [non-optimized agentset code](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-core/src/main/agent/ArrayAgentSet.scala#L160-L169) looks a lot like the list code I already discussed - it iterates each item in the agentset and randomly decides to add it to the result or not:

```scala
val iter = iterator
var i, j = 0
while (j < resultSize) {
  val next = iter.next()
  if (random.nextInt(precomputedCount - i) < resultSize - j) {
    result(j) = next
    j += 1
  }
  i += 1
}
```

Note that this code, for each item in the agentset will perform a couple of arithmetic operations, `precomputedCount - i` and `resultSize - j` as well as the final `<` comparison and the increments for `j` and `i` abd the `j < resultSize` check for the while loop.  It also generates a random number for each checked element (an expensive operation) and calls `next()` to move our agent iterator forward.  If it fills the result set before processing all elements of the agentset it will terminate "early" and save some of the work, but in the worst case scenario it is possible it'll perform all those operations for each element in the agentset when winds up needing the last agent to completely "fill" the results.

2. What does the optimized code do and why is it better??

So now let's check [the optimized code `n = 2` code](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-core/src/main/agent/ArrayAgentSet.scala#L125-L145):

```scala
if (!kind.mortal)
  Array(
    array(smallRandom),
    array(bigRandom))
else {
  val it = iterator
  var i = 0
  // skip to the first random place
  while(i < smallRandom) {
    it.next()
    i += 1
  }
  val first = it.next()
  i += 1
  while (i < bigRandom) {
    it.next()
    i += 1
  }
  val second = it.next()
  Array(first, second)
}
```

First, the check for `kind.mortal` at the start is basically checking if this is a patch agentset or not.  Patches never `die`, so it's safe to assume all agents in the agentset are alive and you can just return the agents found in the backing array at the two provided random numbers as the result.

So on to the second bit.  Here we have to use the `iterator` to get the agents from the set, because some of them might be dead (turtles or links).  The iterator will skip over those for us as we call `next()` to get the next agent.  You see the operations here are doing the `while` checks as it increments `i` up through the desired random numbers.  So here the work is the increments for the indexer, `i`, as well as the checks for the `while()` loops.  We also have to call `next()` to move the iterator forward.  This works because we know `smallRandom` is smaller than `bigRandom` - we're just skipping through the agents and plucking out the ones we want.

Compared the non-optimized version we've avoided generator many of the random numbers, we avoid having an extra variable to track the result set count, and we avoid the math and less-than check to determine memebership in the result set.  That's not bad (especially the RNG operations).

What would the impact be?  Well if you have a large agentset, say 1000 agents, and you are picking 2 of them, the odds of picking any one agent are small (starting at 1/1000, in fact).  That means you will run all that code for a long time before getting your 2 resulting agents.

So why not optimize for `n-of 3`, or 4, or 5, etc?  Well, let's look back at the code to run the optimized version:

```scala
case 2 =>
  val (smallRan, bigRan) = {
    val r1 = rng.nextInt(precomputedCount)
    val r2 = rng.nextInt(precomputedCount - 1)
    if (r2 >= r1) (r1, r2 + 1) else (r2, r1)
  }
  randomTwo(precomputedCount, smallRan, bigRan)
```

That little logic at the end `if (r2 >= r1) (r1, r2 + 1) else (r2, r1)` makes sure that `smallRan < bigRan`; that is **strictly less than, not equal**.  That logic gets much more complex when you need to generate 3, 4, or 5+ random numbers.  None of them can be the same, and they all have to be in order.  There are ways to quickly sort lists of numbers which might work, but generating random numbers without repetition is much harder.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! I am not familiar with Java and to be honest I am not too familiar with many broad computer science concepts - in fact, I am mainly a model builder with NetLogo. Would you be so patient to explain in greater detail why is there a special case for when `resultSize` is `2`, what is going on there with those two random numbers and what do you mean with "overflow the possible choices"?